# R: Perform multiple if conditions across two data frames of different length using for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I am fairly new to R and have to solve a (for me) quite complex problem -> I hope for your help!

I have 2 dataframes of different length:

```
Product <- c("A1", "A2", "C1", "D1")
Posting_Date <- c("01-2016", "03-2016", "02-2016", "01-2016")

df1 <- data.frame(Product, Posting_Date)

df1
 Product Posting_Date
1      A1      01-2016
2      A2      03-2016
3      C1      02-2016
4      D1      01-2016

Product2 <- rep(c("A1", "A2", "B1", "C1", "C2", "D1"), each = 3)
Sales_Month <- rep(c("01-2016", "02-2016", "03-2016"), times = 6)
Sales <- rep(c(2300,0,2700,250,0,3700), times =3)
df2 <- data.frame(Product2, Sales_Month, Sales)

df2
 Product2 Sales_Month Sales
1        A1     01-2016  2300
2        A1     02-2016     0
3        A1     03-2016  2700
4        A2     01-2016   250
5        A2     02-2016     0
6        A2     03-2016  3700
7        B1     01-2016  2300
8        B1     02-2016     0
9        B1     03-2016  2700
10       C1     01-2016   250
11       C1     02-2016     0
12       C1     03-2016  3700
13       C2     01-2016  2300
14       C2     02-2016     0
15       C2     03-2016  2700
16       D1     01-2016   250
17       D1     02-2016     0
18       D1     03-2016  3700
```

I want to add an additional column to df1 that displays a value of 1 if for every product listed in df1 there are sales > 0 in the corresponding month in df2 (df1$Posting_Month == df2$Sales_Month) and a value of 0 if sales were 0 or <0.

This is what I have tried:

```
for(i in 1:dim(df1) [1]) {
  if (df1$Product == df2$Product2)
    &
    if (df1$Posting_Date == df2$Sales_Month)
      &
    if (df2$Sales > 0) {
      df1$match <- 1
    } else {df1$match <- 0}
}
```

But it gives me several error messages:

```
Error: unexpected '&' in:
"  if (df1$Product == df2$Product2)
    &"
Error: unexpected '&' in:
"    if (df1$Posting_Date == df2$Sales_Month)
      &"
>     if (df2$Sales > 0) {
+       df1$match <- 1
+     } else {df1$match <- 0}
Warning message:
In if (df2$Sales > 0) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
```

The correct output should look something like this:

```
 Product Posting_Date match
1      A1      01-2016     1
2      A2      03-2016     1
3      C1      02-2016     0
4      D1      01-2016     1
```

Can somebody please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Hi, so to help you, multiple conditions in `if` should be written into the same parenthesis, e.g. : `if (df1$Product == df2$Product2 & df1$Posting_Date == df2$Sales_Month & df2$Sales > 0) `. In addition, you need to tell which element you look at, i.e. `df1$Product[i]` instead of  `df1$Product`. Finally you should have a second loop. Indeed for each element of `df1` you should loop over all elements of `df2` to find a match (you can stop the loop with `break`when you found).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way using the popular `dplyr` library.

Basically you want to join the two tables together, and then create a new variable `match` based on whether or not the Sales meet your criteria.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  left_join(df2, by = c("Product" = "Product2", "Posting_Date" = "Sales_Month")) %>%
  mutate(match = as.numeric(Sales > 0)) %>%
  select(-Sales)

  Product Posting_Date match
1      A1      01-2016     1
2      A2      03-2016     1
3      C1      02-2016     0
4      D1      01-2016     1
```

This might throw a warning due to how R treats factors and character variables. Doing something like this for each `data.frame()` would correct it.

```
df1 <- data.frame(Product, Posting_Date, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df2 <- data.frame(Product2, Sales_Month, Sales, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Replicating the code gives me the following warning message: "Warning message:
Column `Product`/`Product2` joining factors with different levels, coercing to character vector" The output shows a value of 1 in every row of the column match

Comment: Yeah, that is due to the way you have the data frames. It works, you can actually ignore that. If you do `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in the `data.frame()` statement that will go away.

Comment: Sorry just saw that you wrote this anyways! Works thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

For a safer way without loops and more efficient.

```
> tmp=aggregate(df2$Sales,list(df2$Product2,df2$Sales_Month),max)
> colnames(tmp)=c("Product","Posting_Date","match")
> tmp$match=ifelse(tmp$match>0,1,0)
> merge(df1,tmp,by=c("Product","Posting_Date"))

  Product Posting_Date match
1      A1      01-2016     1
2      A2      03-2016     1
3      C1      02-2016     0
4      D1      01-2016     1
```

Comment: is there any reason for why you aggregated the data before merging?

Comment: @Morasc To find the max value for each combination, that is to find which combination has >0 values. If you were to merge without aggregating you would do a cross-join, producing even more useless records.

Answer (score 0):

Or using `data.table` join

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[df2,  match := as.integer(Sales > 0), 
        on = .(Product= Product2, Posting_Date = Sales_Month)]
df1
#   Product Posting_Date match
#1:      A1      01-2016     1
#2:      A2      03-2016     1
#3:      C1      02-2016     0
#4:      D1      01-2016     1
```